# Firebase how to give read permission for specific user

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

JSON looks like this:

```
"messages" : {
    "msg" : {
       "-Kr2Qb93tM7yP-J7zuAq" : {
              "text" : "hello",
              "toId" : "EeLIxkOEfhMUlsM8WGnHdgeT8xW2",
              "fromId" : "IxfnlsekOh8WEG2HdgMUMWT8xEeL"
            }
    }
 }
```

How can i only give read permission for "-Kr2Qb93tM7yP-J7zuAq" to user if "toId" 's value contain his uid?

And "fromId" can Edit\delete the snapshot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Firebase Realtime Database Rules to the following :-

```
rules": {

     .
     .

"messages" : {
         "msg" : {
            "$messageID" :{
                ".read" : "data.child('toId').val() == auth.uid",
                ".write": "data.child('fromId').val() == auth.uid"
                          }

                 }
             }
        }
```

Also, what you're asking is pretty basic. So, I would really recommend you to read up on Firebase Rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: Thanks!, When i do observe `queryOrdered(byChild: "toId").queryEqual(toValue: user?.uid)` I get permission denied, So observe wont work only if its `".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"` i'm trying to do that for more secure and maybe decrease data downloading, I'm not sure any idea?

Comment: @Sam Your data structure is fine. The problem is that Firebase Rules go from the bottom to the top and not the other way round. Also, Firebase Rules can't be used to filter queries. I would really recommend you to go through the docs on Rules once. You'd understand all of this so much better!